# How to create a new database for each user in a database using django and mongodb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mongodb, django-models

I'm creating a web app for my school to help manage and store student documents. I'm creating the app in such a way that each student in the school gets their own database to store documents (absent notes, doctor notes, etc.). I am creating this database webapp using Django and MongoDB. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to link MongoDB and Django in such a way that I can have an infinite number of databases. Ideally, I'd like to have it so that each student gets their own database filled with their own set of documents. I was just wondering how (or if it's even possible) to create an infinite number of databases and link it to Django from MongoDB? If so, how would I set up my `settings.py` file and my `models.py` file?

As of now, I have used Pymongo as a simple way to create many databases on the original MongoDB server, but haven't found an "ORM" for MongoDB that works for Django and allows me to create many databases. If MongoDB doesn't work, could I try using something else like PostgreSQL?

Comment: Why have one db/user? Why not choose **what** to display the user and **which of these** is editable (create/read/update/delete) by the user? You could use the user's ID so that you know to tell the client(browser) which objects to fetch & display to the user, as well as use their ID to check for the user's privileges (whether or not he can add/update/delete) some of the things that he sees. Basically, you would have to have an `ownerID` (besides the object's ID itself) for any object in your DB, no matter its type (absent notes/ doctor notes etc.) denoting who created it.

Comment: @M.Ionut That actually makes sense and seems way easier to do. Thank you for the advice. I'll try it out! Thanks again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.